# Nautilus and the visualization of available volumes/partitions

Tags: gnome, nautilus, nautilus-elementary

Today I was wondering something about nautilus: what service/module does use nautilus sidebar to list mounted and unmounted partitions/volumes?

I realize it's not strictly about Ubuntu, but Ubuntu does a peculiar use of nautilus so I was curious about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it uses [GIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIO_%28GNOME%29)/[GVFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS) which belongs to [Glib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glib).

Api documentation can be found [here](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/) and [here](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/stable/).